# Why aren't my IF conditions being met? (checkbox.isChecked(), and checkbox == true methods not working)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm attempting to apply borders to cells conditionally via apps script, but my code is not registering the two (obviously met) conditions. Looking for a logic and syntax check <3

Sheet:
[stackoverflow noobs can't attach images so here's a link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsXyl.png)

Code:

```
function doBorders() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sss = ss.getActiveSheet();
  let doBorder = sss.getRange("A5");
  let checkBox = sss.getRange("B5");
  let checkState = checkBox.isChecked();
    let bRow1 = sss.getRange("A1:B1");
    let bRow2 = sss.getRange("A2:B2");
    let bRow3 = sss.getRange("A3:B3");

  if (doBorder == "Do Borders:" && checkState == true) {
    bRow1.setBorder(false, false, true, false, false, false,'Black', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
    bRow2.setBorder(false, false, true, false, false, false,'Black', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
    bRow3.setBorder(false, false, true, false, false, false,'Red', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
    Logger.log('Conditions met. Borders added.');

    } else
      bRow1.setBorder(false, false, false, false, false, false);
      bRow2.setBorder(false, false, false, false, false, false);
      bRow3.setBorder(false, false, false, false, false, false);
      Logger.log('Conditions not met. No borders.');
}
```

I've tried both checkBox == true and checkState == true. Same result.

Execution Log:
["Conditions not met. No borders."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89ZTZ.png)

Comment: Why did you not enclose the block of statements after `else` in `{` ... `}` ?

Comment: does `.getRange` with a single cell return the cell, or a range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let checkBox = sss.getRange("B5")` gets a Range object, which is different from the *value* in that cell. To test the value, use [Range.getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue), like this:

```
  const checkBox = sss.getRange('B5');
  const checkBoxValue = checkBox.getValue();
  if (checkBoxValue === true) {
    // do sfuff...
  } else {
    // do other stuff...
  }
```

Also observe the `{` curly braces `}` after the `else`.